# How to check mysql database connection is setup and particular table has been created

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am writing a script which checks for mysql table has been created from migration.

```
def is_table_created?(db, table)
    begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |c|
           return c.table_exists?("%s.%s" % [db, table])
        end
    rescue Mysql2::Error, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
        logger.warn(e)
        return false 
    end
end
```

But I don't know whats wrong with it. Every time it raise exception.

Comment: Care to share the error message with us?

Comment: @Shadow Sorry for delay :(
`[11267] No such database: "xyz_development"` this is the exception. I am not able to get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried creating or fixing the spelling of the database?

Comment: Yes i did, create and migrate database when i did `rake db:create rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Then you need to do standard debugging stuff, such as confirming if you are connecting to the right mysql instance, if the mysql user has access to the database in question, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by using mysql2 gem.

```
def is_table_created?(db, table)
    begin
        connection = Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', username: 'root', database: db)
        connection.query("describe #{table};")
        return true 
    rescue Exception => e
        logger.warn(e)
        return false 
    ensure
        connection.close if connection
    end
end
```